# doctrine:schema:create - Column name referenced for relation does not exist for composite relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Basic idea: I have 4 Doctrine entities: Product, Shop, ProductOccurence and Price. A product occurs in one or more shops and prices are tied to both products and shops.

So for instance laptop A (a `Product`) is sold by both shop A and shop B (so there are 2 `ProductOccurence` instances in the DB, linking to the same `Product`, but different `Shop` entities) and has a history of 3 list prices in shop A and 4 prices in shop B (so there are 7 instances in the table for entity `Price`).

When I doctrine:schema:create, I get this error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]                                                                                                                         
Column name `product_id` referenced for relation from TRP\ModelBundle\Entity\Price towards TRP\ModelBundle\Entity\ProductOccurence does not exist.
```

Removing the annotation for `Price::$occurence` (the one with the multiple join columns) solves the issue, but I want to understand why it shows up in the first place. Thanks!

Here's part of `Product.php`

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Array
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductOccurence", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $occurences;

    /**
     * @var \Array
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Price", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $priceHistory;
```

Here's part of `ProductOccurence.php`

```
/**
 * ProductOccurence
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_occurences")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProductOccurence
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Product
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="occurences")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var Shop
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shop")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $shop;

    /**
     * @var \Array
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Price", mappedBy="occurence")
     */
    private $prices;
```

Here's part of `Price.php`

```
/**
 * Price
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="prices")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Price
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Product
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="priceHistory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var Shop
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shop")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $shop;

    /**
     * @var ProductOccurence
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductOccurence", inversedBy="prices")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id"),
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="shop_id")
     * })
     */
    private $occurence;
```

Comment: I think I may have found an answer to my question. What I think is happening is that `ProductOccurences::$product` does not define a `product_id` **Column**, but rather a **JoinColumn**, which appears to be different. So now I don't know how I can use a JoinColumn to be part of another compound foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a [ManyToMany relationship](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional) for your `$occurence` property, not a ManyToOne relationship.

Comment: But why? A `Price`, as per my definition, only makes sense in the context of a `ProductOccurence`.The reason I chose to link the 2 entities by multiple columns is that I want to be able to have access to a `Product`'s prices throughout all `Shop`s where it occurs.

If this wouldn't have been the case, I would have simply created a ManyToOne relationship between `Price` and `ProductOccurence` using a simple field. So I can't see the logic behind using an extra join table where a `price_id` field would never be reused (i.e. when using a ManyToMany relationship).